# Error Processor type not supported after project converted from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010

Tags: c#

The solution, which retains an installer project, was recently converted from 2008 project to 2010.

However, attempts to run the .msi that is created returns the error

```
 "Processor type not supported....
```

If you run the setup.exe, it will error that "the application is designed for a x64 platform but is being installed on an intel"

However, the configuration of the solution, is set to to Any CPU.

I am finding little in the way of possible solutions and have seen where people ran into this converting from 2003 - 2005.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries component in your code by any chance?  And if so, what version? (Look in you .config file - it will be 10.0.0.0 or 12.0.0.0)

Comment: Hard to believe it says "x64 pentium" or "on an intel".  What is the *real* error message?

Comment: @Hans Passant - I thought the same thing.

Comment: The type-o I had in the error message was "pentium" and I updated it with the correction "platform".  This is verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installer projects (assuming you mean the built in Visual Studio Installer stuff) don't expose their CPU type through the build/configuration system. Instead, there is a `Target Platform` property of the project itself (select project in Solution Explorer, open Properties).

This property only supports `x86`, `x64` and `Itanium`, so whatever it's currently set to, it isn't `AnyCPU`.